# get_user_meta returns value twice

Tags: wordpress, meta-key

I have a very simple function that grabs a user's uploaded avatar from usermeta in order to resize it, however, the value is returned twice? I can't for the life of me understand why.

```
$img =  get_user_meta($user_id,'user_avatar',true);

print_r ("<pre>");
print_r ($img);
print_r ("</pre>");
```

returns:

```
http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/iStock_000004361729Small.jpg
http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/iStock_000004361729Small.jpg
```

Why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Ain't the problem when you `update_post_meta`? Check inside PHPMyAdmin for the value of the `user_avatar` meta. Also, try  `var_dump($img);`.

Comment: The value in the database is a single value. It's not in there twice.